# Keeping pagination and screen sizes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.4

I am using the laravel documentation code and have pagination showing through

```
                  {!!$sights->appends(Request::all())->links()!!}
```

The problem i encounter is that i have six pages and that is fine showing all six links with a next and previous button on desktop but when i change the screen size to mobile it is too big and goes down to a second line, how do i get the pagination to fit the screen. Does it respond to CSS or is their php i need to add?

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Comment: yes just 'text-centre' on this, at the moment and its within a container etc

Comment: you can make small links of pagination by adding this class `pagination-sm`

Comment: Yes that makes the links small but doesnt defeat the problem of the pagination showing all links rather than just the first, last and either side of the page im on. so therefore the problem will occur again when i have more pages

Comment: you can use `simplePaginate()` instead of `pagination()` in your controller function, it will only `next & Previous` links.

Comment: Yes, i want it to show next previous, the page im on and the two pages eitherside, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can do this.

`$('.pagination').addClass('pagination-sm')`

By your above code, it will generate pagination class, which is actually work for medium screen. You can also add pagination-lg class.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Not not using Jquery. the problem is that it is not cutting down the pages and is showing them all rather than for example ' previous 1, 3,4,5, 7, next' which is meaning it is going over a few lines.

Comment: You can do the same in JavaScript also. It will handle. If you want I can convert this code in JavaScript. By adding this class, bootstrap will automatically handle responsivnes